# What is this tree with oval leaves and yellow flower?

Tags: identification, trees

I'd like now what this tree is in order to find out how to prune and whether or not the shadow of a rubinia close by is a problem as I have the impression the tree is weak (at least it was the case last year.

The tree has yellow flowers and oval leaves. The fruits/seeds have a similar form as a maple-tree.

Here are some pictures (click to enlargen):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Laburnum × watereri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laburnum) also known as golden chain tree.  The most common cultivar is "Vossii".  I note that all parts of the plant are poisonous. It's a member of the pea family (Fabaceae).

In North America this plant is prized for it's stunning, fragrant,short lived floral display but can be a little fussy.  Not too hot (USDA 7), not too cold (USDA 5).

The tree tends to have weak floppy growth. A program of preventive pruning to decrease the number of top shoots in awkward locations that rub other branches or put too much weight on the base trunk is recommended.

Comment: +1 you beat me to it. In salt lake city they do pretty well in partial shade.